# Unable to programmatically delete an Endpoint in GCP Under Private Service Connection

Tags: java, c#, google-cloud-platform, networking, load-balancing

I created an endpoint in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) that is under `Private Service Connection`.
I can delete the endpoint via console but, not through my code in the API.

I am done with the service directory and Namespace

I need help with Java or C# code for API Calling to delete the created endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Founded for myself.
Call compute service api using global forwarding rule to delete that endpoint.
passing projectid and Name.